# Concatenate string to level of MultiIndex mapped from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I would like to concatenate information to the main index of a multi-index. More specifically, i would like to concatenate the product description of the imported product within the main index column where only the product code is referenced.

Consider the following code...

```
index = [('A', 'x'), ('A', 'y'),
         ('B', 'z'), ('B', 'w'),
         ('C', 's'), ('C', 'q')]

Numeric = [33871648, 37253956,
           18976457, 19378102,
           20851820, 25145561]

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index)


pop = pd.Series(Numeric, index=index)
pop.index.names = ['Imported Product', 'Manufactured Product']


print(pop)
```

Current Result:

```
Imported Product  Manufactured Product
A                 x                       33871648
                  y                       37253956
B                 z                       18976457
                  w                       19378102
C                 s                       20851820
                  q                       25145561
```

Consider that I have a separate dataframe with the following information...

```
  Imported Product    Product Description
   A                  Widget 1
   B                  Widget 2
   C                  Widget 3
```

Desired Result:

```
Imported Product  Manufactured Product
A - Widget 1      x                       33871648
                  y                       37253956
B - Widget 2      z                       18976457
                  w                       19378102
C - Widget 3      s                       20851820
                  q                       25145561
```

The core idea here is to make use of the extra white space that is created in the first column. in my real data, one imported product may go into more than 100 manufactured products, so instead of adding new columns to bring the imported product description, I would prefer to do it in the fashion requested herein, as my multi-index already has too many columns.

While above I have just mentioned product description as an item of information to concatenate into the main index... in my real data there would be other information that I would like to do this with, including information resulting from the computations within python.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: What is expected output?

Comment: To be clear, when I multi index, I create a lot of extra space on the first column. The final desired output is to be able to concatenate information to the main index... I understand that is not possible. The idea is to create a duplicated column, concatenate the info to the duplicated column, and then after all computations, drop the original main index column.

Comment: hmmmm, why do you think it is not possible? It is possible.

Comment: I was told that if I added information to the main index column, it would no longer work as the main index column... in my data, each imported product goes into several manufactured products... the idea is to make use of the precious real estate created in the imported product column by appending other useful information to each row of such column... like for example... product description, product classification code, and etc... I have another data frame that in the first column i have the product code and in the other columns I have the useful information I want to  bring to my multi index

Comment: @jpp, question reformulated. Thanks for the feedback!!

Comment: @TPguru, OK, see updated solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) + [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.map.html) + [`set_levels`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.set_levels.html)

Create a mapping via your `mapper` dataframe and then use `set_levels`:

```
s = mapper.set_index('Imported Product')['Product Description']

new_labels = pop.index.levels[0] + '-' + pop.index.levels[0].map(s.get)
pop.index.set_levels(new_labels, level=0, inplace=True)

print(pop)

Imported Product  Manufactured Product
A-Widget1         x                       33871648
                  y                       37253956
B-Widget2         z                       18976457
                  w                       19378102
C-Widget3         s                       20851820
                  q                       25145561
dtype: int64
```

Comment: jpp, I will be able to test this soon and will let you know if I am able to implement this. Thank you very much for the extremely quick feedback!